# select unique matching rows in SQL based on two columns

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table with 314,044,452 rows which looks like below:

```
id1   id2   amount
---- ----   ------
a     A     2
a     A     1
a     A     3
b     B     1
b     B     5
c     A     6
c     A     6
d     F     2
d     F     3
d     F     4
```

I would like to return a table where only unique matching based on id2 is returned, i.e. rows with A are not returned. Plus the amount is sum of the rows:

```
id1 id2 amount
--- --- ------
b   B    6
d   F    9
```

Is this possible with one query?

Comment: Can you elaborate what mean `unique matching based on id2` You said A are not returned but isnt clear why.

Comment: sure, if various id1 are matched to the same id2 then that won't be a unique matching.  basically if id2 is repeated and id1 is different in the repeats then that row shouldn't be returned in the results

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are searching for?

```
select id1, id2, sum(amount) amount
from <table>
where id2 <> 'A'
group by id1, id2;
```

Comment: Thanks. No, because id2 can be anything is not just A. maybe i should update the example. but for example, if F was repeated with another id1 then that shouldn't be in the results

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(id1), id2, SUM(amount) amount
FROM <table>
GROUP id2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id1) = 1;
```

This remove A because have `id1 = {a,c}`

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly you only want unique pairs that don't share common id2, you would get them like this:

```
select id1,id2,sum(amount) as amount
from 
<table> t 
join (
    select id2
    from <table>
    group by 1
    having count(distinct id1)=1
) unique_groups
on t.id2=unique_groups.id2
group by 1,2
```

given the number of rows, I would actually create a staging table with `unique pairs` first and then join it to the source table. if this doesn't work or takes too long, you can break it down further - first materialize distinct `id1, id2`, then materialize `unique_groups` and then run the query

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT id2, SUM(amount) from "tablename"
   group by id2
```

Let me know if I am missing what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This query is returning your expected output for the given sample data set-

```
WITH A (id1,id2,amount)
AS
(
    SELECT 'a','A',2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a','A',1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a','A',3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b','B',1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b','B',5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c','A',6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c','A',6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd','F',2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd','F',3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd','F',4
)
SELECT id1,id2,SUM(amount)
FROM A
WHERE id2 <> 'A'
GROUP BY id1,id2
```

Answer (score 0):

Before grouping and summing you must exclude the rows that you don't want to participate and you can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select
   t.id1, 
   t.id2,
   sum(t.amount) amount
from (
  select t.* from tablename t
  where not exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where id1 <> t.id1 and id2 = t.id2
  )
) t
group by t.id1, t.id2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r4ZQUVwZvpou5x7CvBNjZB/0).

```
| id1 | id2 | amount |
| --- | --- | ------ |
| b   | B   | 6      |
| d   | F   | 9      |
```